# Using shortcodes in the Site Title

Tags: shortcode, options

I'm using MetaBox for a settings page with custom fields.  I'd love to be able to use their shortcode to pull custom fields into and used as the Site Title.

Does anyone have any ideas on how this or if it can be done?

Thx

Comment: Is **MetaBox** a plugin? If so, you should contact their support team to see if this is possible.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.